# Möbius map from annulus to vertical region

Tags: complex-analysis

Is it possible to find a Möbius map $f$ such that 
        $f(\{z\in\mathbb{C}:1<|z|<2\})=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:1<\operatorname{Re}z<2\}?$
     If,so, find one such function . Else, justify your answer. I solved by this technic: Let $\mathbb{D}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}, S=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<2\},\mathbb{B}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\operatorname{Re}z<1\}$, $T=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\operatorname{Re} z<2\}$. We know Möbius map maps circle or straight line  to circle or straight line and preserved the orientation. See if $f$ be a Möbius map which maps $\mathbb{D}$ onto $\mathbb{B}$, this map also maps $S$ onto $T$.
And the same map also maps the region  {$z\in\mathbb{C}:1<|z|<2$} onto region {$z\in\mathbb{C}:1<\operatorname{Re}z<2$} . So it is sufficient to find a Möbius map from  $\mathbb{D}$ onto $\mathbb{B}$.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
See $1,i,-1$ are three  boundary points of  $\mathbb{D}$ and $1-i,1,1+i$ are three boundary points of $\mathbb{B}$. Take a mobius map $f$ which maps 
    $z_{1}=1\longrightarrow1-i=w_{1}$, $z_{2}=i\longrightarrow1=w_{2}$, $z_{3}=-1\longrightarrow1+i=w_{3}$

Hence $f$ also maps interior points of $\partial \mathbb{D}$ to interior points of $\partial \mathbb{B}$ i.e. maps  $\mathbb{D}$ onto  $\mathbb{B}$.\newpage
$f$ can be obtained by the cross-ratio formula:\begin{equation}
\dfrac{(z-z_{1})(z_{2}-z_{3})}{(z_{1}-z_{2})(z_{3}-z)} = \dfrac{(w-w_{1})(w_{2}-w_{3})}{(w_{1}-w_{2})(w_{3}-w)}
\end{equation}
Calculating get , $w=\dfrac{2z(i-1)}{iz-i-1-z}.$\
This the required Möbius map $f(z)=\dfrac{2z(i-1)}{iz-i-1-z}$ which maps 
{$z\in\mathbb{C}:1<|z|<2$}) onto {$z\in\mathbb{C}:1<\operatorname{Re} z<2$}. 
I don't know whether my solution is correct or not.

Comment: Older version with no work shown at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3564508/möbius-map-from-annulus-to-to-vertical-region

Answer (score 1):

Note that,

$$f(z)=\frac{2z(i-1)}{iz-i-1-z}=\frac{2z}{z+i}$$

A quick check at $f(-\frac32 i )=6$, which is clearly outside the vertical region. Thus, it is not a desired map.

A function that maps 
{$z\in\mathbb{C}:1<|z|<2$} onto {$z\in\mathbb{C}:1<\operatorname{Re} z<2$} is,

$$f(z) = \frac4{z+|z|}$$

which is not of the Mobius, though.

Comment: Yeah, I have made a mistake.So what will be the required map? Any suggestion

Comment: @DavidMinda - I don't think you could achieve the required map with the Mobius.

Comment: why this type of mobius map does not exist?? can u give some suggestion?

Comment: @DavidMinda - One map that satisfies the requirement is given in the answer, albeit not a standard Mobius.

Comment: @Quanto note that the annulus and the vertical strip are not homeomorphic, since the first is doubly connected while the other is simply connected. so more than Mobius, no homeomorphism can map one to the other. I haven't done the computation, but that means in particular that your map shoudn't be injective

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki - it's a good point